# Creating a list of checkboxes with ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-template, angular-ngfor

I have a list of objects that's structured like this:

```js
[{item},{item},{item}]
```

I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes with angular out of this list like this:

```html
<form>
     <input *ngFor="let object of objects" type="checkbox"> {{object.name}}
</form>
```

The checkboxes themselves do show up, but I can't get the name of the object to show with each checkbox. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `*ngFor` on a container to make the range variable be visible inside it. Here I have used `div`, but you can use anything you want.

```html
<form>
   <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
      <input type="checkbox"> {{object.name}}
   <div>
</form>
```

Comment: It works, but it does create some boilerplate. I guess this is the only way to go. Do you think my example didn't work because Angular didn't have the access to the object.name variable?

Comment: Yes, outside `input` it is not visible.

Answer (score 6):

You can use check box with *ngFor as follows.

```
<form>
   <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="object.checked"> {{object.name}}
   <div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `object` variable only exist in the context of the `ngForOf`, in your case, this is the context of the `<input>` element.

You could wrap the `<input>` inside of a `ng-container` element, and bind the `ngForOf` to the last. Like this:

```
<form>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let object of objects">
      <input type="checkbox"> {{object.name}}
   <ng-container>
</form>
```

With this approach, the generated HTML is the same, as the ng-container element is stripped away.

Answer (score 0):

I had to ensure the **for** attribute in the label was the same as the input id:

See snippet here

```
 <div class="m-checkbox-list">
   <label *ngFor="let detectionSource of detectionSources" for="detectionSource_{{detectionSource.id}}" class="m-checkbox">
    <input id="detectionSource_{{detectionSource.id}}" type="checkbox" name="detectionSource_{{detectionSource.name}}" [(ngModel)]="detectionSource.isSelected">
                                    {{detectionSource.name}}
    <span></span>
   </label>
 </div>
```